# equality of Pandas index objects with different dtypes and elements

Tags: pandas

Can anyone explain why this evaluates to true in Pandas (0.18.0):

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> pd.DatetimeIndex(['1971-10-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', 
        freq=None).equals(pd.Index([u'100171'], dtype='object'))
True
```

These index objects have different elements and different dtypes. By what mechanism are they the same?

(I see that the date 1971-10-01 can be written as 100171 in mmddyy format. This shouldn't qualify for equality.)

How do I write an assertion comparing two dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1], columns=pd.DatetimeIndex(['1971-10-01'], 
    dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1], columns=pd.Index(['100171'], dtype='object')
assert df1.equals(df2)  # this assertion succeeds!?
```

that fails because the indexes are in fact different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a pathological case.

```
In [1]: i1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(['1971-10-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [2]: i2 = pd.Index([u'100171'], dtype='object')

In [3]: i1
Out[3]: DatetimeIndex(['1971-10-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [4]: pd.DatetimeIndex(i2)
Out[4]: DatetimeIndex(['1971-10-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

`.equals` attempts to coerce to the same type, so for example strings get coerced (if possible); in this case they are really equal.

I created an issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13286) if someone would like to have a look to see if we can eliminate cases like this.